# Split results in columns

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have results being generated by a log output into a CSV file.

Is there a way with a formula or simple VBA I can split the results so the information for Path is is column A and the corresponding value for Access in in column B?

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\vma\Desktop\VMADMIN\csv
Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\vma\Desktop\VMADMIN\Test
Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\vma\Desktop\VMADMIN\test1
Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\vma\Desktop\VMADMIN\test2
Access : {}

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\vma\Desktop\VMADMIN\Test3
Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljiFQ.png]

Comment: Will this work if the output differs in length? I was hopping for a vba sub that I can execute as the length of output will differ with every log

Comment: Your input file is generated by PowerShell. Apparently you're writing `Format-List` output to a .csv file. Why do you do that instead of generating proper CSV output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very, very crude and not at all bulletproof, but maybe it's a boilerplate for what you're looking for?

```
Sub PathAccessSplit()

  Dim wsFrom, wsTo As Worksheet
  Dim rowFrom, rowTo, lastRow As Integer
  Dim cellVal As String

  Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet2")

  lastRow = wsFrom.Cells(wsFrom.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  rowTo = 1

  For rowFrom = 1 To lastRow
    cellVal = wsFrom.Cells(rowFrom, 1).Text

    If (Left(cellVal, 4) = "Path") Then
      wsTo.Cells(rowTo, 1).Value = cellVal
    ElseIf (Left(cellVal, 6) = "Access") Then
      wsTo.Cells(rowTo, 2).Value = cellVal
      rowTo = rowTo + 1
    End If


  Next rowFrom

End Sub
```

It, of course, assumes your source data is in Sheet1 and the output will redirect to Sheet2.  Easy enough to have it overwrite the existing sheet, but that depends on what you want.